# Automate Windows application login action

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, api, dll

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application which uses a third-party API for external data, the way the API works it requires a username/password upon initialization by prompting a GUI represented as a Winform window, if I put the correct credentials the window closes, the initialization finishes, then data start to come through.

You probably get the twist here, when my ASP.NET work processor starts it starts the API's initialization, therefore I have to literally be on the server where the web app is located to enter username and password for the API to complete the initialization, due to this limitation it will be problematic for me to deploy the web app to production where users need to enter their own API's credentials (yes users also have their own credential for the API).

Is there a solution? I was thinking of writing another application that would wait for the winform login prompt to enter the credential based on the passed username/password from the web application. Is this even possible? If not, is there anyway around it?

Comment: Is this a widely-used third-party API?  Maybe the login form can be avoided entirely, for example if Windows Authentication is used in your ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is indeed a WinForms form used for logon, you can access it via the [OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) collection. From there, you can locate the appropriate textboxes and buttons. If the API is blocking, you may need to do this from another thread. Don't forget to use [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to run your function in the correct thread once you've found the form.

Comment: from the info above - it would seem its a winforms app started not from the same app - so you cannot use OpenForms as its not the same process - it wouldn't be able to interact with the desktop. but.. my take anyways ha

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can search for the running application - but there are a host of problems with this.

1. It is not reliable.
2. It is not reliable : )
3. What session does this window show up in? What if someone isn't logged on - does the process hang?
4. Server deployment as you mentioned is very problematic.

FYI - I dont believe you can use the below mentioned OpenForms collection - as this is a third party app.

You can write a program however to search for this window - but depending on the context (user account/windows session) it runs under you may/may not be able to do anything with it. If it is in the same process as the aspnet account, I cant imagine that it is able to show a window on your desktop so Im imagining there is some other component/account this third party app runs under.

Is there not a way to get any web based access to this API? The solution to this will be a hack of all sorts with trying to use APIs to Findwindow or enumerating the windows of a particular process.

So depending on the account/session it runs under, it 'may' be possible, but quite possible to a whole host of issues.

Not seeing this exact environment though its hard to get a full grasp of whats definitely going on in order to provide another alternative, but if you have no control over this portion and its a desktop app that requires integration with the web, it may be difficult.

The other option could be to (hack warning - this is a total kludge) have a process running as a WCF self hosted application outside of IIS that receives the request and then attempts to find that window and send the appropriate commands to it using the windows api for ex. SendMessage for mouse clicks

see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/63a9faac-5898-4b10-8a2c-4ebe1aab948e